# how to add plus minus button in feature page in opencart

Tags: php, jquery, opencart, opencart2.x

I have make extension for plus & minus quantity in product page, you can view http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=25282&filter_search=addplusminus&filter_license=0
Now what i need is that its work for Feature Product that appear on Opencart home page by default..
So far i have see that on feature.tpl and feature.php only Product Id is send in "**cart.add()**" function and only i need to figure out to send current quantity of product in "**cart.add()**" function but i'm not able to figure out after lot's of working..

Here is my code:

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <i class="fa fa-minus pull-left" id="minus-qty"></i>
      <label class="control-label" for="input-quantity"><?php echo $entry_qty; ?></label>
      <input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $minimum; ?>" size="2" id="input-quantity" class="form-control" />
      <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>" />
   <i class="fa fa-plus" id="plus-qty"></i>
</div>

 //for add button
  <button type="button" onclick="var cartqty = $('#input-quantity').val();alert(cartqty);cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>',cartqty);">
  <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
  <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></span>
  </button>
```

Now Its Working Only For One Product Not For All, How i do this to work for all..

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First you need to change all `#` to `.`, an `id` must not repeated in a page. it must be unique.
Second you nee to change:

```
$('#input-quantity')
```

to:

```
$(this).next('.input-quantity')
```

or:

```
$(this).prev('.input-quantity')
```

Now here is your corrected code, javaScript part:

```
<script>//minus quantity
    $('.minus-qty').css("margin-top", ".2em");
    $('.minus-qty').click(function(){
        var crtval = $(this).next('.input-quantity').val();
        if(crtval < 2){
            alert('Quanty Must Be 1');
        }
        else{
        var cartval = parseInt(crtval) - parseInt(1);
        //alert(cartval);
        $(this).next('.input-quantity').append().val(cartval);
        }
   });

        //add quantity
    $('.plus-qty').click(function(){
        var crtval = $(this).prev('.input-quantity').val();
        var cartval = parseInt(crtval) + parseInt(1);
        //alert(cartval);
        $(this).prev('.input-quantity').append().val(cartval);
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Simply with a vqmod or ocmod xml script.

Comment: Thanks For Answer But i have solve this with myself and my code is like your.
I have solve this using vqmod with "**offset**"

Comment: Yes, you can ask a new question.

Comment: @AnujKhandelwal, if you down voted me, can I ask the reason?

Comment: it should be like <button type="button" onclick="var cartqty = $(this).prev().prev('.input-quantity').val();cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>',cartqty);">

Comment: The minus and plus buttons works perfectly as starter asked. if you mean "add to cart" event, it's another case and not related to this question.